# Understanding the Interaction Between Phonons and Electrons in Solid-State Systems

Tags: phonons

How does the wave-particle duality exhibited by electrons and the wave-like nature of phonons enable their interaction in solid-state systems?

Can you explain the underlying mechanisms that allow for energy and momentum exchange between phonons and electrons, particularly in the context of electron-phonon scattering and the modulation of electronic properties by lattice vibrations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The wave-particle duality applies also to phonons. In any case, whether something is a particle or a wave is not particularly relevant when setting up a scattering problem. Generally, one writes down a Hamiltonian directly, and calculates matrix elements. In my opinion, J. M. Ziman's book "Electrons and Phonons", Oxford (1960) is still among the clearest and most detailed treatments of the formalism in this context.

Comment: I might be lacking the full understanding of how to treat phonons but from what I have read, phonons are quasiparticles. Can we tread quasiparticles the same way as fundemental particles in terms of wave-particle duality? and for the phonon-electron interaction, such interaction would include momentum exchange, and as I know this is a property of particles not waves. Moreover, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Yes, they are quasiparticles or collective excitations, but this doesn't stop them from displaying [decidedly particle-like properties](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189302/49107) under the right circumstances. In particular, the theory of phonons allows for a single phonon to be emitted by a single atom, travel through the material as a wave, and then be absorbed as a single phonon. I'd argue their delocalized nature in-between such events is naturally understood in terms of _crystal_ momentum. Intuitively, wavelength and _crystal_ momentum are related through de Broglie's relation.

Comment: In general, I would recommend never treating anything as a particle in quantum mechanics, just think of "particles" as having localised wavefunctions.

Comment: @PhilHasnip Thank you sir for this insight

Comment: Was this question answered in the comments? In your comment that said "I would like to extend the question", it looks like you're asking a new question, which would be more appropriate in a separate post. Anyway, @Anyon *might* not have even seen that follow-up question that you asked, because you didn't use the @ character to ping the username.

Comment: @NikeDattani I would like to keep the question for a while, maybe someone would add a complete answer or I would answer that eventually based on the comments. You are right I sound like I have asked another question within the comments, but I think it is a natural extension of Anyon first reply. Thank you ~

Comment: It is best if you ask all questions separately since [comments are "temporary post-it notes"](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and "when they are deleted they're gone for good". By asking a separate question, it will also be seen by more people and therefore the probability of it getting answered will be higher. It will also be good for the site to have more questions, more participation, and more material for search engines to direct people to discover this community. Comments are also limited to a small number of characters, which makes it hard for answers.

Comment: @NikeDattani I got your point, thank you again for the clarification.